Constant current driver issue or misunderstanding
I want to learn how to use a constant current driver. After some research I ordered an  NSI45030AT1G driver which delivers 30mA from 10V to 40V according to the datasheet. After a real testing, I am more confused. I used two LEDs, a 20k potentiometer, and the driver.

The measured current was not constant if the resistance was changed. Isn't that the main purpose of this driver?
My assumption was: if the resistance increases, the voltage goes up to 40, the driver help me to deliver a constant 30mA.
What is wrong in my understanding?
LE: Please excuse me if in schematic potentiometer is not connected right, but in real life was good (I measured resistance changes when turned left and right.)

What is the purpose of RV1? There’s a fair chance you were burning it as the average potentiometer probably wouldn’t  appreciate 30mA flowing through it. Besides, D2 is varying its resistance to maintain the current. The test technique I’d suggest is a multimeter with current measurement and a variable power supply. At around 7 to 8V the leds should be conducting and 30mA flowing. Increase the power supply voltage and the current should remain constant at 30mA.

The current regulator device needs about 2V across it to regulate properly. If I assume your LEDs drop 3V each, that's 8V total. With a 12V supply that leaves 4V for the resistor.
At 30mA and 12V nominal, the maximum resistance that the circuit can tolerate will be 4V/0.03A = 133Ω.
With a 10kΩ pot, it will barely be off the end of the element (and, as Kartman says, could damage the pot itself).
If you want to test the regulation, put a 100Ω resistor in series
instead of the pot, and measure the change in current with the series resistor vs. a short. That will allow a bit of voltage (about 1V) for multimeter burden and tolerances.

So,  for my understanding , current is mentined constant only if voltage change? Not if the load is changed? Or please explain me, when regulate the current

The device needs 2V or so across it to regulate well. So the sum of the total LED voltages plus resistor drop must add up to less than 12V - 2V = 10V. So it would regulate with 3x 3V LEDs in series (and no resistor) but not 4. If you want it to regulate with higher voltage drop you have to increase the supply voltage. There are also thermal limitations and voltage limitations so if you have too much voltage across the regulator it could overheat or break down. When all the constraints are satisfied you are okay.

At 40V and R=0, you would have 34V across the regulator so the device would have to dissipate about 1W to regulate. That's well beyond what it is capable of it, even at room temperature, and it would likely be damaged. At a more reasonable 250mW you would be limited to about 14 or 15V supply voltage with 2 3V LEDs.

Thank you, tomorrow I will try with 2 and 3 LEDS without any resistor to check what happened and come back with some feedback,  I think I get it. I have less current because resistor "eat" to much?

Yes, that’s about right.

Thank you, I just tested and you were right. Thank you! How is mention in data sheet that drop voltage across current constant driver?

It's called "voltage overhead" and is listed at 1.8V, but that is not full current at 1.8V (it is 75% according to the note) and there will be a temperature effect. Figure 1 also gives an idea of how it typically behaves- the curve doesn't flatten completely until 10V. Good enough for LEDs visually.
